# Sorting heterogeneous elements in arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

How to sort heterogeneous elements in a array-list? For example,

```
ArrayList l1 = new ArrayList(); 
l1.add(1); 
l1.add("hi"); 
l1.add(1.0f);
```

Now how to sort this array-list?``

Answer (score 2):

You would have to implement your own `Comparator` which compares the least upper bound of all involved types. In this case, `Object`.

Related question (from yesterday):

- [how to compare on multiple classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092450/how-to-compare-on-multiple-classes-in-java?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Define computable *sorting rules*. Then implement those rules in a class that implements `Comparator` and use

```
Collections.sort(l1, myComparator);  // myComparator is an instance of the class
                                     // you just implemented
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want them sorted. You could split the list up into new ArrayLists with a defined type, sort each one of them then concatenate them?

Something like: (pseudocode)

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> stringList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// ...etc

for (Object o : list) {
  if (o.getClass().equals(Integer.TYPE))
    intList.add(o);
  else if (o.getClass().equals(String.class))
    stringList.add(o);
  // ...etc
}

sort(intList);
sort(stringList);
// ...etc

concatenate(intList, stringList, ...);
```

That's what I'd think you do anyway.